# How to prove that the following object is not a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let us consider $C: = \{\lambda \in \text{Card} \ / \ \omega + \lambda = \lambda \}$ (note that we consider here the operations on ordinals and we work in ZFC). I want to prove that $C$ is not a set.

It seems to be an easy question of elementary set theory but I cannot figure out which arguments to use (in general, this kind of question is linked with the Russell's paradox.)

Any hints would be helpful. Moreover what would happened if we took $\lambda \in \text{On}$ ? Will $C$ be a set then ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal then $\omega+\lambda = \lambda$. So it boils down to noting that the class of infinite cardinals is not a set

Comment: @Jakobian nice remark ! I'll try to prove that $\{\lambda : \lambda \ \text{is an infinite cardinal}\}$ is not a set.